# Ajax form submit no result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a signup page. I do a JQuery validation and then make an AJAX call to regForm.php to upload the new user if all of the fields are correct - pretty basic.

**My problem**

The validation is working but, when user registers, NOTHING HAPPENS. I get no success or error message, nothing written to the database, and my console on Chrome shows nothing. So I am pretty much stuck.

I'm sure it is just a small problem.... Perhaps something I'm missing?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="ajaxMsgDiv"></div>
        <form name="registration-form" id="regForm" method="post" action="regForm.php">
         <span id="sname-info" style="color:red"></span>
        Name: <br /><input type="text" id="sname" name="fName" onfocus="this.value='';" /><br />
        <span id="ssurname-info" style="color:red"></span>
        Surname:<br /> <input type="text" id="ssurname" name="fSurname" onfocus="this.value='';" /> <br />
        <span id="sspword-info" style="color:red"></span>
        Password:<br /><input type="text" id="spword" name="fPword" onfocus="this.value='';" /><br />
        <span id="sconfirmpword-info" style="color:red"></span>
        Confirm Pword:<br /><input type="text" id="sconfirmpword" name="pwordConfirm" onfocus="this.value='';" /><br />
         <span id="sEmail" style="color:red"></span>
        Email:<br /><input type="text" id="sEmail" name="sEmail" onfocus="this.value='';" /><br />
         <span id="sPhone-info" style="color:red"></span>
        Phone:<br /><input type="text" name="sPhone" id="sPhone" onfocus="this.value='';" /><br />
        Male<input type="radio" value="male"  name="sex">Female<input type="radio" value="female" name="sex"><br />
        <input type="submit" onclick="" value="Register" name="register" class="buttono" />
        </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var form = $('#regForm');
    var formMessages = $('#ajaxMsgDiv');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function (e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        //do the validation here
        if (!validateReg()) {
            return;
        }

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        }).done(function (response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).html(response); // < html();

            // Clear the form.
            $('').val('')
        }).fail(function (data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success').addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            var messageHtml = data.responseText !== '' ? data.responseText : 'Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.';
            $(formMessages).html(messageHtml); // < html()
        });

    });

    function validateReg() {
        var valid = true;

        if (!$("#sname").val()) {
            $("#sname-info").html("(required)");
            $("#sname").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }

         if (!$("#ssurname").val()) {
            $("#ssurname-info").html("(required)");
            $("#ssurname").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }

         if (!$("#spword").val()) {
            $("#spword-info").html("(required)");
            $("#spword").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }  


        if(!$("#sEmail").val()) {
        $("#sEmail-info").html("(required)");
        $("#sEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#sEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
        $("#sEmail-info").html("(invalid Email)");
        $("#sEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }

        if(!$("#sPhone").val()) {
        $("#sPhone-info").html("(required)");
        $("#sPhone").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }

        return valid;
    }
})
```

Comment: Is request sent?  What is response from the server? You can track it in network tab in devev tools/firebug.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr I think that is the problem the request is not being sent form some or other reason because im getting no response from server...

Comment: @Marilee can you try after removing this `onclick=""` from your submit button.

Comment: @Jai will do and let you know..

Comment: @Jai didnt help...The request is not being sent I cant see why it is not being sent....its just weird I can not spot the error to save my life

Comment: Are your validations working @Marilee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation function always returns "false", that is why request isn`t sent. This happens because email validation never passes:

```
if(!$("#sEmail").val()) {
}
```

In its turn, that happens due to fact that you have a span and an input with same id. Try to 
change it:

```
<span id="sEmail" style="color:red"></span>
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cs65xfn/